# How to filter emails list by domains and count it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I got emails and domains lists. I need to take only domains from domains list and count it. Here is short example of arrays and function countDomains:

```
const emails = ['info@gmail.com','info@hotmail.com','admin@host.com','felix@hotmail.com','alex123@host.com'];
const domains = ['gmail.com','hotmail.com'];

const countDomains = (emails) => {
result = emails
  .filter(email => domains.includes(email.split('@')[1]))
  .reduce((acc, email) => {
    acc[email] = (acc[email] === domains.includes(email.split('@')[1]));
    return acc;
    }, {});
 return result;    
}
console.log(countDomains(emails));
```

I have trouble with this line:
`acc[email] = (acc[email] === domains.includes(email.split('@')[1]));`
just have no idea how to write this. can any one help?

Comment: can you please specify what is the output you need?

Comment: i need list of counted email in every domain ```{ 'gmail.com': X, 'hotmail.com': X,}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with single `reduce` over the array. Create a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of domains. If the Set [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) the current domain, add or increment the accumulator based on whether the key exists using the `||` operator

```js
const emails = ['info@gmail.com', 'info@hotmail.com', 'admin@host.com', 'felix@hotmail.com', 'alex123@host.com'];
const domains = ['gmail.com', 'hotmail.com'];

function countDomains(emails, domains) {
  const set = new Set(domains);
  
  return emails.reduce((acc, email) => {
    const domain = email.split('@')[1];
    if (set.has(domain))
      acc[domain] = acc[domain] + 1 || 1;
    return acc;
  }, {})
}

console.log(countDomains(emails, domains));
```

If you don't want to use `Set`, just replace `set.has()` with `domains.includes()`

Answer (score 3):

You could instead use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) with `.map()` to map your `domains` to a `[key, value]` pair array, where each `value` is the length of the filtered array which [`.endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) the current `key`:

```js
const emails = ['info@gmail.com','info@hotmail.com','admin@host.com','felix@hotmail.com','alex123@host.com'];
const domains = ['gmail.com','hotmail.com'];

const res = Object.fromEntries(
  domains.map(d => [d, emails.filter(e => e.endsWith(d)).length])
);
console.log(res);
```

Currently, [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) has limited browser support. Alternatively, you could use a `new Map()` instead of an object:

```js
const emails = ['info@gmail.com','info@hotmail.com','admin@host.com','felix@hotmail.com','alex123@host.com'];
const domains = ['gmail.com','hotmail.com'];

const res = new Map(
  domains.map(d => [d, emails.filter(e => e.endsWith(d)).length])
);
console.log(res); // See browser console for output
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var domain = email.split('@')[1])
acc[domain] = (acc[domain]) ? acc[domain] + 1 : 1;
```

Comment: ty! changed my code to <br>    const countDomains = (emails) => {
result = emails
  .filter(email => domains.includes(email.split('@')[1]))
  .reduce((acc, email) => {
    acc[email.split('@')[1]] = (acc[email.split('@')[1]] ? + 1 : 1);
    return acc;
    }, {});
 return result;    
}</code> and got   {gmail.com: 1
hotmail.com: 1} only 1 for every domain. may be its just me did something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If domain not found then set the domain value to 1 and if you get a recurrence just increment it by 1.

```js
const emails = ['info@gmail.com','info@hotmail.com','admin@host.com','felix@hotmail.com','alex123@host.com'];
const domains = ['gmail.com','hotmail.com'];

const countDomains = (emails) => {
result = emails
  .filter(email => domains.includes(email.split('@')[1]))
  .reduce((acc, email) => {
     var domain = email.split('@')[1];
     acc[domain] = acc[domain] ? acc[domain] + 1 : 1;
     return acc;
    }, {});
 return result;    
}
console.log(countDomains(emails));
```